# WPF Rounded Corners on a Border in a Window Without AllowsTransparency

Tags: wpf, xaml, browser, transparency, rounded-corners

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474204/wpf-rounded-corners-background-bleeding-through), but I have a window that cannot have "AllowsTransparency=True" because the WebBrowser inside it would be rendered invisible. The corners of the window come out black and I need them to be transparent.

Changing the background color to transparent has no effect. I've found that you can wrap a border with rounded edges around a popup with this problem, but you can't do that with a window.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="False">

    <Border Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="100" Background="AliceBlue">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">v This is a webbrowser v</TextBlock>
            <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="5">
                <WebBrowser />
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Any ideas?

---EDIT---

I've tried every form of the [WebBrowser Overlay solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changov/archive/2009/01/19/webbrowser-control-on-transparent-wpf-window.aspx), but my specific problem can't use it. I need a solution that has AllowsTransparency="False".

Comment: Before you do AllowTransparency="True" you should add WindowStyle="None" to your window.

Comment: you just want rounded corner on the window containing a webbrowser?

Comment: Xcalibur- Thanks I added WindowStyle="None" and ResizeMode="NoResize", but it still doesn't solve my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have a problem of interop between webbrowser window and a wpf window

so when you set wpf window to be transparent it effectively make the browser transparent as browser is in the hierarchy of the main window

so the whole idea to overcome this issue is to host a browser in a separate native window and overlay it on the transparent wpf window

you may follow [WebBrowser control on transparent WPF window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changov/archive/2009/01/19/webbrowser-control-on-transparent-wpf-window.aspx)

Comment: I've tried this solution, but my specific problem won't allow this, because I can't track my parent window as they do in the example to have the overlay effect. I really need AllowsTransparency="False".

Comment: could you post a picture of your expected output?

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post pictures.

Comment: you may try posting a link to the picture instead of the picture itself.